# Is possible to recover whole app when it is killed(by user or by android), or at least get last activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

Assuming that the user closes the application through "recent applications" or that Android for whatever reason closes the application, I then want to recover the last activity that the user was in, is there any way to do this, by Android standards, or do I need to create sophisticated schemes?

Ex:

Activity A -> B -> C

then user swipe to close app / android close it

on reopen, should go to Activity C

Thanks in advance for any help.

Ps:Is it possible to recover backstack aswell?

Comment: `onDestroy()` will be called when your application closes. This is both applicable to closing it using the back button, or from the recent applications.  You can save a flag during this process into your shared preferences and use it to restore whatever activity you would like

Comment: By Android's schemes, a task clear means all Activity records are dead. If you want to create custom navigation scheme, you probably should be using 1 Activity, track navigation state yourself, and rely on either Views or Fragments so that you can easily initialize any backstack for proper back navigation upon restoration.

Answer (score -3):

not a piece of expert advice but you can try saving an instance of last activity in shared pref. n get the value of shared pref on the start of application to directly navigate to that last instance page from splash activity.

On every startActivity(); action replace previously shared pref value with new activity value.

Comment: and give me an answer please :), i really need this to work...
btw i rather have other solution then using shared pref.

Comment: You are downvoted because it is not possible to put an Activity instance into what's basically a string-keyed key-value storage and in reality an XML file, meaning your answer is not only wrong, but conceptually impossible. The idea also wouldn't take back navigation into account.

Comment: When you post an answer, it suggests that you know what you're talking about, so the OP might try it and waste their time and be less informed than when they started. If you're guessing at a solution, post it as a comment.

Comment: @RuiAlves What about SharedPreferences makes you want a different solution? There is no easier way to store simple data that will survive your app being killed.

Comment: the thing is that i wanted to recover backstack included, if possible